# Combination of mutate and select in dplyr - problem with column names of result

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using a `select` inside of mutate and this leads to a problem, that the defined column names in the `mutate` call are not used.

A small example to illustrate the issue I am seeing is the following

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate("a" = select(., ncol(.)) - select(., ncol(.)-1)
                 ,  b = select(., ncol(.)-1)*4
                 , c = carb* gear
                  )

result 
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb carb gear  c
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    0   16 16
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    0   16 16
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   -3   16  4
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   -2   12  3
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   -1   12  6
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   -2   12  3
```

The result is that the `a` and `b` column are called `carb` and `gear` respectively, a call without a `select` results in the expected name of the column.
I am using this to always select the last and second to last columns. If there exists an easier/better way to always select these two I am happy to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
mtcars %>% 
 mutate(across(last_col(vars = names(.)), .names = "a") - across(last_col(offset = 1, vars = names(.))),
        across(last_col(offset = 1, vars = names(.)), .names = "b") * 4,
        c = carb * gear)

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  a  b  c
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  0 16 16
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  0 16 16
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 -3 16  4
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 -2 12  3
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 -1 12  6
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 -2 12  3
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4  1 12 12
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 -2 16  8
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 -2 16  8
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4  0 16 16
```

`last_col()` is one of the recent select helpers. It has an offset parameter which allows you to select the nth variable from the end.

Comment: But this results in the same problem that the columns are not named like defined in mutate. :)

Comment: I totally missed that part, sorry :) See updated.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, I can't replicate your results. I am on `dplyr` 1.0.0, so perhaps this is caused by a bug in older versions.

Comment: I'm using `dplyr` 1.0.0 and `tidyselect` to 1.1.0.

Comment: Thanks, I do have the same versions, so no idea where the issue might stem from.

Comment: Try a new R session, probably some functions are masked.

Comment: Works in a new session, so I'll need to check which functions might mask the command.